# How to insert using generatedId in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

When I tried to insert a data into table, I always get a `Exception` said `id` is `NULL`.
Here is the code:

```
@Insert({
    "insert into device (tag)",
    "values (#{tag,jdbcType=VARCHAR})"
})
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id", keyColumn = "id")
int insert(Device record);
```

Also I tried to add

```
@SelectKey(before = true, keyColumn = "id", 
    keyProperty = "id", 
    resultType = Integer.class, 
    statement = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
```

But still got the error. Then I run the sql(`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`) and get a null.

The environment is: `MyBatis 3.4.0`, `SQL Server 2008`, `Spring-Boot`

Comment: Could you post more details about exception?

Comment: @Reno It shows that can't insert a null into a non-null column. Seems that mybatis set the column `id` to NULL. So I guess `SELECT SCOPE_INDENTITY()` get a null.

Comment: Hmm, your column `id` is auto increment? This error seems to be a sql error.

Comment: now I have to edit the table to add the auto-increment strategy. But I still don't know how to insert a data with a generated key. You can see the code above, it's not a error. I googled many demos like mine. @Reno

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `before=false` in your @SelectKey annotation.